# Previous & Next links on horizontally scrolling pages

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a (section of a)page that scrolls horizontally using the following JS:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
var sildeNum = $('.page').length,
    wrapperWidth = 100 * sildeNum,
    slideWidth = 100/sildeNum;
$('.wrapper').width(wrapperWidth + '%'); 
$('.page').width(slideWidth + '%');

$('a.scrollitem').click(function(){
    $('a.scrollitem').removeClass('selected');
    $(this).addClass('selected');

    var slideNumber = $($(this).attr('href')).index('.page'),
        margin = slideNumber * -100 + '%';

    $('.wrapper').animate({marginLeft: margin},500);
    return false;
});
});
```

My primary nav scrolls the page vertically, and subnav scrolls horizontally. How can I create prev/next links for the horizontal section (moving between panels)?

Here's a demo to explain:
http://cloudlevel.me/test

Comment: Prev/Next in the panel menu or in the panel itself?

Comment: Outside the panel - roughly where my placeholder links are on the example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here are your onclick functions

```
function previous(){
    var slideNumber = $($('a.scrollitem.selected').attr('href')).index('.page') - 1,
            margin = slideNumber * -100 + '%';
    if(slideNumber >= 0){
        $('.wrapper').animate({marginLeft: margin},500);
        $('a.scrollitem').removeClass('selected');
        $('a.scrollitem').eq(slideNumber).addClass('selected');
    }
}
function next(){
    var slideNumber = $($('a.scrollitem.selected').attr('href')).index('.page') + 1,
            margin = slideNumber * -100 + '%';
    if(slideNumber < $('.scrollitem').size()){
        $('.wrapper').animate({marginLeft: margin},500);
        $('a.scrollitem').removeClass('selected');
        $('a.scrollitem').eq(slideNumber).addClass('selected');
    }
}
```

and these are your links

```
<nav>
  <a href="#" id="previousLink" onclick="previous();">Previous</a>
  <a href="#" id="nextLink" onclick="next();">Next</a>
</nav>
```

we're using the exact same semantic it's using when navigating from left panel menu. just setting the current one, that's all.

Comment: Thank you Emre. When the selected panel is the last one, clicking 'next' increments the margin once more, showing an empty panel. Same when clicking previous on the first panel. If I click 'next' on the last panel, then click 'previous' on the empty panel, it shows another empty panel. Demo updated to illustrate. How can a prevent this?

Comment: yeah, my bad. i couldn't think of that scenario. well it depends on you actually. if u want to stop moving in the first and last panel towards empty panel, then u should just check the slide number in the appropriate manner. if u want to slide to the other end of the panel when u reach the edge, i mean first and last, then u should just update the slide number and continue executing as usual. i'll update my answer shortly

Answer (score 0):

Calculate the divs' sizes then move the horizontal scroll on click using jQuery's scrollLeft(val) function.